# Python TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I have to design and implement a `TwoSum` class. It should support the following operations:

- `add` - Add the number to an internal data structure.
- `find` - Find if there exists any pair of numbers which sum is equal to the value.

Here is my code:

```
class TwoSum(object):

    dict = {}

    def add(self,n):
        dict[n] = n #TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

    def find(self,n):
        for i in range(0,len(dict)+1):
            if dict[i] == None:
                continue

            val = n - dict[i]
            if dict[val] != None and val != i+1:
                return True
        return False

test = TwoSum()
test.add(1)
test.add(3)
test.add(5)
print(test.find(4))  # True
print(test.find(7))  # False
```

I got error message

> TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment for "dict[n] = n"

Any help or suggestion? Thank you so much!

Comment: What's this code supposed to do?

Comment: Python instance attributes should be created in `__init__`, not at class level, and you need to access them through `self`.

Comment: Also you're overwriting the python's `dict`. Rename it so something like `numbers_dict`

Comment: Reading your requirements you are using the wrong data structure too. You should be using a list not a dict for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lot of issues here, I'll try to go through them one by one

#### The data structure

```
dict = {}
```

Not only is this <s>overwriting python's dict</s>, (see mgilson's comment) but this is the wrong data structure for the project. You should use a list instead (or a set if you have unique unordered values)

#### Using the data structure

The data structure is an instance variable, it needs to be defined with `self` and inside the `__init__` function. You should be using something like this:

```
class TwoSum(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = []
```

#### def add

```
def add(self,n):
        dict[n] = n
```

Assigning items to a dictionairy is not the way to do it. You should instead append to your list. Additionally you need to append to the list for that instance using `self.variableName = value`

#### def find

That range is wrong, and you would need a nested range, or itertools.combinations since you have to check for any two numbers that sum to a certain value, pythons `sum()` is handy here.

To loop through the numbers you can use two ranges or itertools.combinations

## The code

```
import itertools

class TwoSum(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.numbers = []

    def add(self, num):
        self.numbers.append(num)

    def find(self, desiredSum):
        for nums in itertools.combinations(self.numbers, 2):
            if sum(nums) == desiredSum:
                return True
        return False


test = TwoSum()
test.add(1)
test.add(3)
test.add(5)
print(test.find(4))
print(test.find(7))
#True
#False
```

#### Def find without itertools

```
def find(self, desiredSum):
        for num1 in self.numbers:
            for num2 in self.numbers:
                if num1 + num2 == desiredSum and num1 != num2:
                    return True
        return False
```

Comment: FWIW, I don't think that it _is_ overwriting python's `dict` -- At least not in any way that matters.  It is creating a class attribute with the name `dict`.  Any code outside of the class (including in the class's methods) won't be affected.

Comment: @mgilson Isn't it overwriting it inside that scope though? I might be wrong here.`>>> dict = {}` and then 
`>>> dict()` gives `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`. http://i.imgur.com/YJboc6x.png

Comment: Just the scope of the class instantiation -- It's pretty limited (right now, that scope only has one user-defined thing in it).

Comment: Thank you so much, man. Your comment and solution are amazing. I learned a lot. Really appreciate them.

Comment: @Tang By the way if this is for homework you are going to want to use two nested ranges instead of itertools.combinations since you probably haven't covered that

Comment: @Keatinge, this is not for homework. I just used it for practice. I am wondering. Why do we use dictionary? The purpose I use dictionary is in order to reduce time complexity.

Comment: @Tang dictionaries are for when you have one key mapped to one value. That isn't what you have. I used a list because I thought you would need to include duplicates. If you don't care about duplicate numbers you can decrease the time by using a set instead of a list, but definately not a dict.

Comment: Nice explanation to me. It totally make sense to me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The `dict` at the class level and the `dict` in the method are different

In the method, `dict` is the builtin python type.  If you want to modify the `dict` on the class, you could try something like `type(self).dict[n] = n`

Also, for what it's worth, if your dict is always going to have the value == key, you might want to consider using a `set` instead.

Finally, you'd probably be better off defining `dict` as an instance attribute rather than a class attribute:

```
class TwoSum(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.added_items = set()  # Make the `dict` -> `set` swap here too...
    def add(self, n):
        self.added_items.add(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class TwoSum(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__data = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.__data)

    def add(self, n):
        self.__data.append(n)

    def find(self, n):
        for i, v in enumerate(self.__data):
            for x, v2 in enumerate(self.__data):
                if i!= x and v + v2 == n:
                    return True
        return False
```

Comment: Any reason for the double underscore?  In my experience, that is used very infrequently -- and only to avoid conflict with names in subclasses.

Comment: I try and use `__name` for any variable name that is used to store data to avoid accidental data loss. using the __ makes the variable nearly (but not entirely) unobtainable/changeable from outside the class. It is completely not necessary for a program of this scope but it has become almost habitual to me at this point!

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. This solution works. Really appreciate your time and work.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my solution, just another reference for any potential people
>   who may see this question. Basically, I combined all above answers to
>   get this solution. Credits to @Keatinge, @mgilson, @TheLazyScripter.
>   Thank you guys all.

```
class TwoSum(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.added_items = set()  # Make the `dict` -> `set` swap here too...
    def add(self, n):
        self.added_items.add(n)
    def find(self, n):
        for nums in itertools.combinations(self.added_items, 2):
            if sum(nums) == n:
                return True
        return False

test = TwoSum()
test.add(1)
test.add(3)
test.add(5)
print(test.find(4))
print(test.find(7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering this late but I wanted to add some input after reading the other posts. Especially @keathige and anyone else that tells you not to use a dictionary for this problem.

The easiest way for me to explain this would be exploring the solution to this problem if you use a list as your ADT in your class.

let's say you call the find function and your list as N items in it. each item in the list would potentially have to compare itself with every other item in the list to see if there's a pair of numbers. So worst case you would have to check each element of the list N time and compare that with each other element in the list N times. In other words your function would have to do N * N operations to find a solution, which is O(N^2) [I'm not gonna dive to much into time complexity but having a O(N^2) is typically really bad!!].

On the other hand if you use a dictionary you could cut down the operations by the power of (1/2), aka taking the square root.

if you loop through each element in the dictionary one time you can check if a solution exists with math.

sum (the sum you're trying to check is possible with the numbers in your class)

item ( the current element in the dict you're looking over)

x ( if you add x to item it equals sum)

sum and item are given. So to find x, you can do (x = sum - item) then check if x is in your dictionary.